# Need code sugg. for my spec to create small admin application

Tags: node.js, laravel, lumen

My Spec : Login, Logout, dashboard, I need to render 150 inputs in single form, need to download pdf file for saved inputs. And each inputs need to save input blur action and also form submission.

The existing application has build nodeJs with expressJs with jade template for rendering. Backend(mySql) connection has builded laravel (lumen).

FrontEnd - NodeJS, ExpressJs, Jade template
Backend - Laravel Lumen

Provide some suggestion to best language for my requirement to code.

Had some suggestion like

1. Laravel + VueJs
2. NodeJs + ExpressJs + ReactJs
3. NodeJs + ExpressJs

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered just using Adobe Acrobat straight-up?

Comment: @Brad need to build small application which contains login, logout, 3-5 forms and pdf generation. so kindly suggest best suitable coding language.

Answer (score 1):

You can create REST API using NodeJS and Express framework. If it just uploading file and auth you can use middleware function and the library you can use like multer and jsonwebtoken for uploading and user validation.. i prefer hbs instead of jade because it HTML based. 
I hope this helps

Comment: well, can you please provide one more details. need to generate pdf file and need to download. if i use node packages like require('html-pdf'). It generating more than 4MB size (6-8 pages, no images)

Comment: multer convert it to binary type and can save it to your database lighter